# Issue with rounding aftrer division of BigDecimal values. Java

Tags: java, rounding, precision, division, bigdecimal

I've got a problem with the result of division of BigDecimal instances.
My program:

public class DecimalPrecision

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MathContext mathContext = new MathContext(25, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("0.1111111111111111111111111").divide(new BigDecimal("3"), mathContext).toString());

    }
```

The result is the following:
      0.03703703703703703703703703
But the correct result is:
      0.03703703703703703703703704

Basically my program rounded the last digit, which is 7, to 3, not to 4. Why is it so? In mathContext I specified rounding mode HALF_UP. Probably I've got a gap in knowlegde on the issue but I was sure that HALF_UP rounds to a bigger value.

This problem can be sorted out in the next way:

```
    value1 = value1.divide(value2, 10000, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return new BigDecimal(value1.toString()).round(mathContext);
```

But in my taste there's something wrong with parsing the result to a String and then create new properly rounded BigDecimal. I'm asking for your help, how can I resolve this problem without resorting to any strings? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting with a 25 digit number and performing an operation with a precision of 25 digits so you can expect that the last digit might be wrong.  The solution is to use more digits than you need and round the result.

```
BigDecimal oneNinth25 = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(9), 25, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
BigDecimal oneNinth26 = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(9), 26, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
MathContext mathContext = new MathContext(25, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

System.out.println("1/9 to 25 digits / 3 = " + 
                   oneNinth25.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3), mathContext));
System.out.println("1/9 to 26 digits / 3 = " + 
                   oneNinth26.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3), mathContext));
```

prints

```
1/9 to 25 digits / 3 = 0.03703703703703703703703703
1/9 to 26 digits / 3 = 0.03703703703703703703703704
```